# Android: Can i load JNI Library in Activity class rather than Aplication class

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've made an application that uses some JNI Libraries. It is working fine as expected. I am able to load the library in Application class in a static block as following

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libName");
    Log.v(TAG, "Library Loaded");
}
```

but in my application i Have an activity that responds to `android.intent.action.VIEW` intent. This activity has an `Intent-Filter` as following

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
      <data android:scheme="http" />
 </intent-filter>
```

So when i click on a link in the phone and choose my application this activity is launched but the problem is am not able to call the Native functions properly because this block never get called

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libName");
    Log.v(TAG, "Library Loaded");
}
```

Although when i launch the app on clicking the application icon then the library is loaded properly and everything works fine. but when coming to the app by clicking a link, Library is not loaded.
So if there is anyway to load the Library within the activity so that each time the activity is launched the library is loaded and i shall be able to make calls to JNI functions.

I've tried writing this static block in my Activity class as well. But same problem occurs here. when i launch the activity from the app then the static block executed and the library is loaded, but when i launch the activity via clicking on a link then the static block in the activity is not executed. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can load JNI libraries in `Activity` in same manner as you load them in `Application`. Just put the static block within the class to load JNI libraries as below:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    static {
       System.loadLibrary("libName");
       Log.v(TAG, "Library Loaded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
       // onCreate code here
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this too. but i'm facing very strange behaviour. when i am launching this activity with in the app then the static block is executed but when coming to the app by clicking a link. then the static block not executed :(

Comment: static is executed only once per lifetime of application process (PID), maybe it is already running from previous start? Android does not clear static variables till low of memory or application is swiped from tasks

Comment: I am also loading library in Actvity class and launching it from launcher activity on button click but still my app is crashing with the error A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x718296 in tid. Can you please guide me? And I am uninstalling and reinstalling application.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution. Actually problem was not that i thought. JNI Library was loading correctly. So We can load the library in a static block written with in the Activity class.

But the static block gets execute once only in lifetime of application (PID). Thanks anyways